# wcf and wpf application source code for beginner

Tags: wpf, wcf, .net-3.5

I am beginner for .net 3.5, have to work on app where I need to build desktop version as well as web version for selected modules like reporting. I think WCF will help me out to create a base from where I could call functions in both(desktop as well as web )

Let me know the any available source code sample projects to go through. It would be good if those are following any design pattern like MVC.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx) is a good place to start with WCF

and [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) is a good start with WPF.

Have Fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the <s>[DinnerNow.net](http://www.dinnernow.net/)</s> sample application.  There's quite a bit that goes into setting it up but I think if you're ready to tackle both technologies at once it'll help a great deal.